# SPARQL Query questions in WSO2 DSS

Tags: authentication, wso2, sparql, wso2-data-services-server, fedora-commons

I've got a question with using WSO2 DSS and SPARQL queries in Fedora Commons. At the moment I'm running WSO2 DSS from my desktop machine and accessing it as a localhost service. My SPARQL endpoint is a remote server, running an open source application called Fedora Commons, requires basic authentication to preform a query and accepts input via GET or POST requests with the content of the query being placed in the "query" var. For the sake of this example, we'll say the the endpoint URL I'm attempting to query looks like this:

```
http://fedoraAdmin:fedoraPW@fedora-server.yoyodyne.com:8080/fedora/risearch?lang=sparql
```

The query I'm attempting to run works in the Fedora Resource Index Query Service test page and looks like this:

```
PREFIX fedora:  <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#>
SELECT ?pid
FROM <#ri>
WHERE  {
  ?pid fedora:isMemberOfCollection <info:fedora/islandora:root>
}
```

At some point I'd like to replace the identifier of "islandora:root" with a query param, but that's not important at the moment. The result of the above query look something like this:

```
<sparql>
    <head>
        <variable name="pid"/>
    </head>
    <results>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/islandora:sp_basic_image_collection"/>
        </result>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/islandora:sp_large_image_collection"/>
        </result>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/islandora:70"/>
        </result>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/rick:1"/>
        </result>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/islandora:419"/>
        </result>
        <result>
            <pid uri="info:fedora/islandora:420"/>
        </result>
    </results>
</sparql>
```

Given the above situation and data output, I have created a data service in WSO2 DSS that resembles the following:

```
<data name="FedoraSPARQL">
    <config id="FedoraDEVServer">
        <property name="rdf_datasource">http://fedoraAdmin:fedoraPW@fedora-server.yoyodyne.com:8080/fedora/risearch?lang=sparql</property>
    </config>
    <query id="getMemberOfCollection" useConfig="FedoraDEVServer">
        <sparql><![CDATA[PREFIX fedora: <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#> SELECT ?pid FROM <#ri> WHERE {?pid fedora:isMemberOfCollection <info:fedora/islandora:root>}]]></sparql>
        <result element="results" rowName="result">
            <element column="pid" name="pid" xsdType="string"/>
        </result>
        <param name="targetPID" sqlType="STRING"/>
    </query>
    <operation name="getMemberOfCollection">
        <description>Returns the collection objects under islandora:root</description>
        <call-query href="getMemberOfCollection">
            <with-param name="targetPID" query-param="targetPID"/>
        </call-query>
    </operation>
</data>
```

Currently I'm experiencing a 401 Unauthorized likely due to either a typo or formatting error in the connection string or the fact that WSO2 DSS may not be able to connect to an SPARQL endpoint requiring authentication. My question here is how do I make the above data source work given my current setup? If I can't get authentication working with DSS, I do have the option of bypassing authentication completely if WSO2 DSS were running from another server. Assuming this can be made to work, what change do I need to make to use the "targetPID" query param in place of the "islandora:root" string currently used?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think i see the problem with this approach. Wow, I totally misunderstood what a RDF data source operation is supposed to do. Funny how more coffee tends to make things a bit clearer.

When going through the Edit Data Source configuration I see that the property name of "rdf_datasource" in the configuration XML is listed as "RDF File Location" in the data source editor wizard. That make me think that DSS isn't sending any query to the Fedora server as I had hoped but is executing the query (locally) on a pre-existing RDF result it expects to download from the Fedora server.

I guess I need to restructure this as a Web Data Source to get the result I'm expecting.